# ng-class not working properly in 'AngularJs'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In following program, as I type **red** in the **input box**, the paragraph must turn red in background. Also, why **by default** I am getting blue background in paragraph (It should be transparent as model is having null value on page load? Can someone help me ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <style>
    .red{background:red;}
    .blue{background:blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="color" />
    <p ng-class="{'red':color==red,'blue':color==blue}">This is a paragraph.</p>
<script>
    //1 module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //2 controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
        //code here
    });
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Use quotes in the string comparison. `ng-class="{'red':color== 'red', 'blue': color== 'blue'}"` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x1t2outd/)

Comment: You Equality to an object but in input you pass a string

Comment: You are comparing if undefined equals to undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any variables `red` or `blue` defined anywhere, so their value evaluates to `undefined`, which passes comparison differently than you expect.

Compare to the ***strings*** `'red'` and `'blue'`, with quotes.

Comment: Doesn't answer why `blue` by default

Comment: Because with the broken comparison `blue` is applied, and it has the highest precedence for the `background`.

Comment: [Tried in Chrome latest console. It gives `false`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vtp9why4/)

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that statement. Angular's comparison works a bit differently (it doesn't throw a ReferenceError for one).

Comment: In Angular terms then: *model with no value equals non existing variable*.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your code with:

```
<p ng-class="{'red':color==='red','blue':color==='blue'}">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

By default you had the following expression:

```
color==blue
```

By default color = null and the variable blue is undefined.
So the expression null == undefined returned true, that's why your paragraph was in blue.

Comment: But then same was case of red. Then why not red ?

Comment: Try to swap like this: 'blue':color==='blue','red':color==='red' and it will be red ;)

Comment: Ho ho ... Fred still question is same, why not first comparison and only the last or second one!

Comment: Cause you use the '==' comparator and not the '==='.
With == -> null == undefined return true.
With === -> null === undefined return false.

Comment: @Peterson Inspect your DOM. *Both* classes should be applied. But in your CSS rules, blue overrides red!

Comment: Now, that was the answer I was searching! ;)